# Kingswaysoft record update: Is there a way to add a variable that increases eacht time with +1

Tags: derived-column, kingswaysoft

What I have is
productname: playstation
productname: xbox

What I want is:
productname: product 1
productname: product 2

I'm using a derrived column to achieve this but can't find a way to add a variable that increases each time with +1

Is there a way to concatenate a string "product" with the row number for example?

Answer (score 0):

If you use our **Premium Derived Column** component, you could easily achieve this using the **RowIndex()** function that we offer. Premium Derived Column component is part of our [SSIS Productivity Pack](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-productivity-pack) offering.